# Check if ViewData is null before setting DropDownList to it

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this:

```
<% if (ViewData["roots"] != null) {%>
       <%Html.DropDownList("roots"); %>
<%}%>
```

But it's not working. How to check if ViewData exists?

Comment: @amit_g ViewData["roots"] is still not defined and the program crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not outputting anything and are incorrectly using the DropDownList helper. Try like this:

```
<% if (ViewData["roots"] != null) { %>
       <%= Html.DropDownList("roots") %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
ViewData.ContainsKey("roots")
```